# Onclick on Google map marker but not when panning the map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm using something like this (javascript):

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(new_marker, 'click', function(e) {
  alert("hi");
});
```

But I don't want it to trigger when the user moves the map, and they just happened to do so while clicking on the marker. To be clear: I only want the code to run when the user clicked on the marker, without moving the map. How can I do that?

Comment: usually the click does not fire while dragging the map, which browser are you using?